# Errors when connecting to an offline .cub file by using C# ADOMD Connection

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, ssas

I'm trying to connect to an offline .cub file via ADOMDConnection

ADOMDConnection aConnection = new ADOMDConnection();
aConnection.ConnectionString="DataSource=D:\Downloads\Market\updated.cub;Catalog=Market;";
aConnection.Open();

It always invoks an error with the message" A connection cannot be made.Ensure that the server is running"

I have set SQL Server Browser to be running as well as create a rule in the firewall for the port of Analysis Service..

now I'm lost on the issue. Please give me some hints

Comment: Setup the database using following : https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/40306.adomd-net.aspx?force_isolation=true  The is something wrong with the connection string and the database cannot be found.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.